# What's going on with the two-dimensional Helmholtz equation?

Tags: greens-function

I've come to realize that its somehow harder to find results for this equation than for the three-dimensional one.

For example the wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) on Green's functions has a list of green functions where the Green's function for both the two and three dimensional Laplace equation appear. Also the Green's function for the three-dimensional Helmholtz equation but nothing about the two-dimensional one.

The same happens in the [Sommerfield condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerfeld_radiation_condition) article. The condition is written in a generic fashion, depending on the number of dimensions $n$, but when it's time to show an example showing the solution of a point source only the three-dimensional case is shown.

Is it just a coincidence? or the solution to the point source in the two dimensional case:
$$
G\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right)=\frac{i}{4}H_0^1\left(\kappa\left\vert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\right\vert\right)
$$
is not a true Green's functions for some reason?